# How to write a bidirectional mapping in Go?

Tags: go, mapping

I am writing a simple console game and would like to map a player to a symbol. With two players my approach looks like this:

```
func playerToString(p player) string {
    if p == 0 {
        return "X"
    }
    return "O"
}

func stringToPlayer(s string) player {
    if s == "X" {
        return 0
    }
    return 1
}
```

Of cause you could also write this as two maps mapping int to string and string to int. Both the above approach and the map approach seem error-prone. Is there a more idiomatic way to write this in go? Maybe some non-iota enum way?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question and therefore probably off-topic.

Comment: That said, in general consider switch statements for this sort of thing in every language.

Comment: Not sure if this was opinion-based. Might have been that there was a clear guide how to do that @BadZen

Comment: Closing as off-topic seems a bit hasty. OP has asked a reasonable question for which there are two or three answers in Go, some of which may be more appropriate or idiomatic in some cases than others. @User12547645, can you give us a bit more context? What is "player"? Will there ever only be two players, etc?

Comment: Let's wait a few more hours. Maybe there will be a clear idiomatic answer to this question

Comment: In theory there may be as many players as you like

Comment: Yeah, I think it's *worthwhile* maybe, and I did say "probably".  But - non-opinion-based answers should be testable / falsifiable.  I don't see how any answer to this could possibly be so.

Comment: I'm confused by how you call it "unidirectional mapping", then show the conversion in both directions.

Comment: You are right. Should have been bidirectional @HymnsForDisco

Comment: Possibly of interest (though the implementation uses generics and is concurrency-safe): https://jub0bs.com/posts/2020-07-21-go-bimap/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[I assume your example is just minimal and that your actual mapping has more than two options. I also assume you meant bi-directonal mapping]*

I would write one map:

```
var player2string = map[int]string{
  0: "0",
  1: "X",
  // etc...
}
```

And then would create a function to populate a different map `string2player` programmatically. Something like this:

```
var player2string = map[int]string{
    0: "0",
    1: "X",
    // etc...
}

var string2player map[string]int = convertMap(player2string)

func convertMap(m map[int]string) map[string]int {
    inv := make(map[string]int)
    for k, v := range m {
        inv[v] = k
    }
    return inv

}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(player2string)
    fmt.Println(string2player)
}
```

[Try it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iUW0JekG1N8)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Eli's answer, two other changes you could make. You could make the to-symbol function a method of the `player` type. And because the player values are integers (sequential starting from zero), you can use a slice instead of a map to store the int-to-symbol mapping -- it's a bit more efficient to store and for lookup.

```
type player int

var playerSymbols = []string{"X", "O", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"}

func (p player) Symbol() string {
    if int(p) < 0 || int(p) >= len(playerSymbols) {
        return "?" // or panic?
    }
    return playerSymbols[p]
}
```

This method signature could even be `String() string` so it's a [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer), which can be useful for printing stuff out and debugging.

Comment: Thank you. I like the `fmt.Stringer` option. That really makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need any specific mapping and the player integer values have the sequence 0,1,2,3,...,25, you can generate the players symbols directly without using the maps as shown in following snippet :-

```
type player int

func ToSymbol(p player) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%c", 'A' + p)
}

func ToPlayer(symbol string) player {
    return player([]rune(symbol)[0] - 'A')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this thread down the line I wanted a more ergonomic solution for bi-directional value mapping so I created a small module to do this. If anyone is looking for a ready made solution.

https://github.com/graytonio/go-bidirectional-map

```golang
myMap := bidmap.NewMap(map[string]int{
    "foo": 3,
    "bar": 4,
})

fmt.Println(myMap.GetP("foo"))
// Output: 3 true

fmt.Println(myMap.GetS(3))
// Output: foo true
```

Edit: Added example code